# How to write a graphQL mutation that allows for partial updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

So I'm working on trying to learn GraphQL for ruby for a project.

I've almost got some parts of it up and running, but I'm having issues with other parts.  There are plenty of tutorials out there that cover ultra-basics, but none of them seem to expand in the right directions.

I have a mutation to update my user.  So far so good.  I can look up the user by their ID, and update a single specific field.  I can extend that to updating two fields.

What I *cannot* do, and this is looking insane, is generalize those fields -- at all.  My user model will wind up with over 20 fields attached to it -- phone numbers, addresses, job title, etc etc.

When I create the mutation, I have to define the arguments that go into the resolve method.  So far so good.  I then define the fields the mutation can return.  Again, so far so good.

Then I get to the actual resolve method.

The initial syntax isn't bad.  `def resolve(user_id:, name:, email:)`.  Then you discover that despite setting required to false, you have to include all the values.  You need to specify default values for the optional variables.  So it becomes `def resolve(user_id:, name: null, email: null)` -- but that actually nulls out those values, you can't do partial updates.  Worse yet, imagine having 20 fields you have to set this way.  You can play games by trying to convert the arguments into a dictionary and rejecting null values -- but then you can't set properties to nil if they need to be nil again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: a double splat operator.  Your syntax becomes `def resolve(user_id:, **args)`.  From what I can tell, it turns all remaining named arguments into a dictionary -- and I think unnamed arguments would become an array.  *Not* sure how it would react with a mix of the two.

Full model becomes:

```
  argument :user_id, ID, required: true#, loads: Types::UserType
  argument :name, String, required: false
  argument :email, String, required: false

  field :user, Types::UserType, null: true
  field :errors, Types::UserType, null: true

  def resolve(user_id:, **args)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    if user.update(args)
      {
        user: user,
        errors: []
      }
    else
      {
        user: nil,
        errors: user.errors.full_messages
      }
    end
  end
end
```